# Permissions for local development with git and MAMP

Tags: wordpress, git, permissions, localhost, mamp

I'm setting up a new machine on a clean account. I'm developing locally on a Mac (OSX 10.8.2) with MAMP Pro and I use git for version control. I'm having a permissions problem...

MAMP Pro allows you to set permission to the host directory using the following dialog: 
[image]

When I set the owner to myself (ESL) and the group to "Admin" git works happily, but Wordpress updates on my local machine aren't able to run normally (I get prompted for ftp credentials).

When I set the owner and group to "www", Wordpress updates smoothly, but git throws "Permission denied" errors such as:

```
ESL$ git checkout master
fatal: Unable to create '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/streetofwalls/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
```

I'm stuck because I need Wordpress to run normally as well as git. Any ideas why I'm having this problem and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow everybody to write there. It’s just local dev machine, right?

Comment: Correct. Just my local dev machine. Is there any risk of exposure to my local server from the outside web when my machine is connected to the internet? I don't fully understand how localhost is partitioned from the web.

Comment: The permission dialog you posted a screenshot of is only for local access rights. It you give rights to everyone (group+other) in there, you still need an account on your computer to access your repo. So no – this setting is not a security thread.

Comment: Did you mean for me to use the "get info" to add read+write to the directory (and it's contents) or did you mean for me to change the checkboxes in that dialogue. I did the former and it seems to work. At least git doesn't complain, and wordpress didn't prompt me for ftp credentials. For some reason my admin area has no CSS style applied now, which may or may not be connected to this issue.

Comment: Update: I re-installed wp-admin folder and everything seems fine now. Probably was just an artifact from the previous botched attempt to update. Thanks for your help!