# How do I set MAMP PRO permissions for localhost?

Tags: wordpress, mamp-pro

I am using MAMP PRO for local development on WordPress and have to constantly change permissions, depending on whether I'm working the files, or from the WordPress dashboard. Surely there must a catch all permissions settings that will allow access for both?

[image]

If I set the Owner to me 'Storm', I can freely edit the files in sublime, without getting prompted to allow access when I save, but then some things in the WP dashboard don't work (such as updating plugins, where I get prompted to enter FTP details)

If I set the Owner to _www, I can update plugins freely, but then I get prompted to allow access when I save files.

This is really frustrating. What is the correct way to set permissions so I never get prompted locally? I have tried the suggestion [on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612537/permissions-for-local-development-with-git-and-mamp) but when I try make to make all files writable, it doesn't change the boxes (see the message in the image, which says that you can't change boxes with dashes in them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to run the webserver as Storm instead of www[1], ie. the same user as the one you're editing files with (due to the way WordPress checks permissions).

[1] See General in the main window of MAMP.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! I can now do everything prompt-free! Not sure if I should be concerned about the line underneath that setting: "If your Mac is connected to the Internet, it is - for security reasons - highly recommended to start the servers as users www/mysql."

Comment: That's because the website will be able to read everything else your account has access to, your mail, documents, settings, etc., because those files are under the same user. So only use this setup for local development sites.